# how to write a query with a where clause using greenDao

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, greendao

I am trying to write a simple query that contains a group by and a where clause in greendao however I am getting an error when I add in the where clause . Is there another way to write the where clause so that I can get this to work

I am basically getting the day part of today and subtracting 1 so that I can upload data from the previous day.

```
 public  List<AppTimeUsage> LoadAppTimeUsageData() {

     List<AppTimeUsage> items = new ArrayList<>();
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     int previousDayCheck = thisDay -1 ;
     String sqlWhere;
     sqlWhere = "WHERE DAY_RECORDED = " + previousDayCheck;
     String sql = "SELECT APP_NAME , SUM(APP_TIME_SPENT) , DAY_RECORDED  FROM APP_TIME_USAGE " + sqlWhere + " GROUP BY APP_NAME ; ";

     Cursor c = appTimeUsageDao.getDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
     int offset = 0;
     int d;
     int cd;
     String e = "";
     while (c.moveToNext()) {
         AppTimeUsage atu = new AppTimeUsage(
                 Long.MIN_VALUE,
                 new Date(),
                 c.getInt(1),
                 c.getString(0),
                 c.getInt(2)
                 // break;
         );
         items.add(atu);
         //stats = atu;
     }
     return items;
 }
```